# How to call a controller action in Laravel 4.1 and get the filters executed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So the title describes my problem pretty well I think, but let me explain why I want to do this as theremight be an other solution to my problem that I haven't thought about.

Let's say that I have a route specifying the class of the object it will patch:

```
Route::patch('{class}/{id}', array(
  'as' => 'object.update',
  function ($class, $id) {
    $response = ...; 
    // here I want to call the update action of the right controller which will
    // be named for instance CarController if $class is set to "car")
    return $response;
  }
));
```

This is something pretty easy to do with `$app->make($controllerClass)->callAction($action, $parameters);` but doing it this way **won't call the filters** set on the controller.

I was able to do it with laravel 4.0 with the `callAction` method, passing the app and its router, but the method has changed now and the filters are called in the `ControllerDispatcher` class instead of the `Controller` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I might have found a solution to my problem, it might not be the best solution but it works. Don't hesitate to propose a better solution!

```
Route::patch('{class}/{id}', array(
  'as' => 'object.update',
  function ($class, $id) {
    $router = app()['router']; // get router
    $route = $router->current(); // get current route
    $request = Request::instance(); // get http request
    $controller = camel_case($class) . 'Controller'; // generate controller name
    $action = 'update'; // action is update

    $dispatcher = $router->getControllerDispatcher(); // get the dispatcher

    // now we can call the dispatch method from the dispatcher which returns the
    // controller action's response executing the filters
    return $dispatcher->dispatch($route, $request, $controller, $action);
  }
));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have routes declared for your classes then you may use something like this:

```
$request = Request::create('car/update', 'POST', array('id' => 10));
return Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
```

In this case you have to declare this in `routes.php` file:

```
Route::post('car/update/{id}', 'CarController@update');
```

If you Use this approach then filters will be executed automatically.

Also you may call any filter like this (`not tested` but should work IMO):

```
$response = Route::callRouteFilter('filtername', 'filter parameter array', Route::current(), Request::instance());
```

If your filter returns any response then `$response` will contain that, here `filter parameter array` is the parameter for the filter (if there is any used) for example:

```
Route::filter('aFilter', function($route, $request, $param){
    // ...
});
```

If you have a route like this:

```
Route::get('someurl', array('before' => 'aFilter:a_parameter', 'uses' => 'someClass'));
```

Then the `a_parameter` will be available in the `$param` variable in your `aFilter` filter's action.

Comment: Well, this would require me to write `Route::post('car/update/{id}', 'CarController@update');` for all the different types of objects that I have. Am I wrong?

Comment: For the first one yes, you have to declare routes for each one.

Comment: But that's the whole point for me, I have many different object models that have the same route ({class}/update for instance) and I don't want to write them all in the `routes.php` file

Comment: Did you try the `Route::callRouteFilte` ?

Comment: I think I might have found a solution to my problem, I don't know it it is very clean though. See my answer if you want to tell me what you think about this solution! Thx

Comment: Not bad, +1 for your effort :-)